# search button display unnormal

Tags: html, css, drupal, search

http://run.xxmn.com/new/

the search button on the top of the site displays unnormal under IE8,chrome, which is lower than the search textbox. i want the top of the search button  can  parallel with the search textbox . but it's ok in IE7,6 and firefox. why? how to alter it.thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Apply `float: left` to your search input and button. I'm not sure if it will solve your problem entirely because I can't test it in IE right now.

Comment: it's ok. many many thanks. why adds the float: left ,it displays normal.